# Anyone been successful growing mangos or papayas in a greenhouse?

Tags: greenhouse

I live in Northern California where it is not hot enough to grow really juicy citrus.  So i bought a greenhouse.  I was also wondering if I could be successful growing really tropical fruits.  Has anyone tried mangos for papayas in a greenhouse?  If so, any tips?